# Ошибка при сборке проекта pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 433, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 522, in assemble
    icon.CopyIcons(tmpnm, self.icon)
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 177, in CopyIcons
    return CopyIcons_FromIco(dstpath, [srcpath])
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 134, in CopyIcons_FromIco
    for i, f in enumerate(icons):
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 104, in __init__
    entry.fromfile(file)
  File "c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 65, in fromfile
    self._fields_ = list(struct.unpack(self._format_, data))
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 16 bytes
```

Запрос выглядит вот так `pyinstaller --icon=parser-icon.ico --noconsole main.py`

Выдаёт такую ошибку. Программа работает нормально.

Убрал пункт про иконку. Собралась. Но теперь вопрос. Как мне поставить иконку? Иконка имеет разрешение 32x32

Comment: @Эникейщик расширение картинки 32x32 пикселя

Comment: @Эникейщик Всё правильно у меня...

Comment: @Эникейщик не понимаю смысл вашего комментария Б) Смотрим разницу между расширением и разрешением.

Comment: Посмотрите разницу между этими двумя терминами. 32х32 пикселя это не расширение.

Comment: @Эникейщик извиняюсь, писал с телефона. Только сейчас заметил

Comment: Ок, не проблема.

Comment: @Эникейщик А вы не знаете как исправить? Почему не собирается?

Comment: Скорее всего, картинка неправильного формата (судя по гуглу на текст ошибки).

Comment: @Эникейщик написано, что картинка должна быть с расширением .ico

Comment: И нужного формата. Просто переименовать, например, png в ico не получится. Нужно сконвертировать.

Comment: @Эникейщик дело в том, что я просто переименовал :D Сейчас попробую сконвертировать